# How to make multilingual forms and xbl components without orbeon form runner?

Tags: orbeon

What is the best way to make multilingual forms and xbl components outside the form runner?

Comment: See my answer below. But besides that your question is way too generic to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Form Runner ;) Sorry I realize it's not a satisfying answer, but the reason Form Runner was developed was to make that kind of functionality available without the boilerplate.

Properly answering this question would require explaining how Form Runner works, which might be a good thing to do but which is outside the scope of this reply.